# Microsoft graph api password last changed

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

How to get the date the current user change the password in active directory using azure graph api?
I want to show the number of days to expire the current password in a sharepoint hosted add-in.

Comment: It's not possible, currently, but you should definitely request this at https://feedback.azure.com

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have added a request in feedback.azure.com on this.

Comment: Is any info available now on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, this is not currently exposed in either the Azure AD Graph API nor in the Microsoft Graph API.